# Puzzle "railway game set"

Tags: no-computers, puzzle-creation

Alisa completes a railway game set which allows us to make various closed railway routes with crossroads. It is need to put the “rails” parts in the kit, as well as four types of “crossroads”: corner (L), through (I), tee (T), central (X). To draw up the route, a dice is used, which is thrown three times. The number of points determines the number of rails that you need to take to compose part of the route. After the first throw, the rails must be connected by crossroads in a straight line, then take the crossroad (L, T or X), which allows you to turn right at a right angle and connect with the rails, the number of which determines the second roll of the die, the rails are connected in the same way after the third roll.

Further, the process will be repeated using the points from 1st step, until the route closes at the original intersection.

What is the minimum number of parts that Alisa needs to put in a set to make a closed route in which all intersections are used to connect the rails?

**Question.** I need help in checking the uniqueness of the puzzle's statement.

Comment: What do you mean by "uniqueness"? Whether it's an original idea? Whether there's only one way to understand it? Also, I presume your don't want people to post "answers" which solve the puzzle, is that right?

Comment: @bobble, The "uniqueness" means one solution. Yes, I hope my idea is original. At first, I want to formulate puzzle. Then I want to present the puzzle to the community.

Comment: The reason for my last question is there was a previous post asking for how to reword a puzzle, that got answered by the solution to the puzzle. Obviously this was entirely off-topic but the poster argued it was fine since the puzzle creator didn't say they couldn't. Would you rather have answers under this question, or in a separate question once you have the wording locked down, basically?

Comment: I would rather have answers in a separate question after the wording will be locked.